# Help with blender stains on texture

Tags: texturing, materials

I'm fairly new to blender and i am working on a project for a friend, and i finished almost everything, and now i am stuck at this. I can't make the stains go away, to make the inside of the shoe evenly colored.

[image]

Edit:

here is the file:
[image]

Comment: Hello, maybe share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: i just uploaded the file, didn't know you could do that, sorry about that.

Comment: I can't see these artifacts in 2.9, I'm not sure there's anything wrong, the normals are ok and it doesn't look like there are vertices or faces overlapping... but maybe someone will understand...

Comment: I suppose the stains are from a clear white texture i tried to add, and they don't appear if you are not viewing textures. Some of the texture settings seems to be doing that, but i cant figure out which.

Answer (score 1):

Your mesh is correct except several materials are assigned to it and one is displayed in *Solid* mode:

[image]

If I turn it orange:

[image]